# Efficient way of storing multiple time series of different length in one file

Tags: python, data-structures, time-series

I am trying to find the best file structure that I can use to store and process multiple  different length time-series, for example:

```
pitch_track_for_audio1, 105, 108, 96... (60 values) 
pitch_track_for_audio2, 125, 132, 94... (58 values)
pitch_track_for_audio3, 115, 130, 99... (93 values)
```

where pitch_track_for_audio# is the index and the numbers after it are time series corresponding to the index.

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.11-working-with-time-series.html I've looked at python's pandas' dataframe but it expect each rows to be uniform size.

One hacky way I can think of doing this is to save the time series as a string so I can store it in a column of a dataframe and use the index to find the row it's in and convert it back to a series for processing. But I was wondering if there is a more efficient way (in terms of both memory and speed)

Comment: Wouldn't simply pickling list work in your case? You could transform integers to `uint8` or similar to gain some space as well. What do you want to do with it afterwards (after unpickling)?

Comment: essentially I have a bunch of different algorithms that I can then apply to the time series and this file would just be an intermediate way of storing data without having to reprocess the audio file. The problem is that I could have 1000s of audio files so I would have 1000s of rows of time series in this file so I don't want to have to pickle and unpickle a list everytime I want access to a specific row.

Comment: JSON / Dictionary rarely disappoints. Otherwise u can use numpy arrays or a pandas dataframe with NaN filled in empty locations.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj hmm I was thinking of json and dataframe but they both seem to have drawbacks. I heard Json can be slow and putting nan in a dataframe feels inefficient when there's a large difference in lengths between timeseries. 

At this point I am just creating a file per timeseries and using the filename for lookup. would json/dataframe provide an advantage over this method if I have a lot of time series?

Comment: @kkawabat If when processing the data, you never need more than one time series in memory, there is absolutely no reason to use dataframe or JSON. Best way would be cache in files and process only the relevant data when you need it.

I was under the impression that you needed all the data at once which is why I suggested JSON / Dataframe. The positive is you can process all the data at once or run a function on it if you wish.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj I see, although I wont need to use multiple time series at once, I was trying to reduce any overhead that exists with having the data in separate files. In my mind I felt that if each individual file has some time/memory overhead in reading and writing it might become substantial if I have thousands of files.

Comment: @kkawabat If you can fit all your data in the Heap memory, that would be the faster approach, though this program design won't be very scalable.
If you cache all your data in files, it will be slower, though it can be scaled up to a large amount of data.